# Can someone identify this tree from these leaves and this "fruit"?

Tags: identification, trees

[image]

Can someone identify this tree that I have growing at my home from these leaves and this "fruit"? The ground is covered with the green, plum like orbs but they are rock hard. The tree itself is at least 30 feet tall and recently was damaged by a falling branch during a storm.

We live in the state of Virginia in the USA. We live in the middle of five acres of all kinds of trees so getting the age of the tree will be hard but we have lived here for forty years so at least that old.

It is currently summer here, temps in the 80s & 90s. The storm dislodged the "fruit" and in the winter we find hard, dark brown nuts of some type beneath these trees. I'll try to get a photo of the whole tree tomorrow.

Comment: Welcome to the site Onepaw! Would you please add a picture of the whole tree? Also, a few more details. Where do you live? What's your season right now? How old is the tree? Have you seen it fruit before? Have these fallen off sooner than usual, perhaps in the storm? It sounds like they're not ripe yet. Especially with [identification](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) questions, the more we know, the easier it is to help. You can just press this [edit] and add the information into the question. We look forward to helping you!

Comment: Looks a little like Quince (Cydonia oblonga)? But the serrated leaves and height don't sound right.

Comment: It could be *Celtis australis* if you are in southern part or Europe

Comment: Hi Onepaw. I copied the text from your edit summary (which is intended for descriptions of any changes made to the post) into the post itself. Hope you find an id for your tree!

Comment: Perhaps Celtis occidentalis: http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=a858

Comment: What we really need for ID is to know whether the leaves are composite, opposite, as well as what the bark looks like, so an image of a branch with leaves at the very least is essential. It's age is relatively unimportant, but your USDA zone might be useful to know.

Comment: Because we need more information in order to make a definite identification, I'm voting to close this as "unclear what you're asking." Onepaw, we haven't seen you in a while, but if you come back, feel free to add the pictures and anything else you can think of, then ask for it to be opened back up! I'm sure lots of people would like to know what this is!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is *Celtis tenuifolia*, but to be really sure we need more photos (and possibly the flowers).